# How SSH port forwarding over the internet

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, telnet, anydesk

I want to access my remote devices SSH server Attached My remote PC (mostly a router or Raspberry Pi No internet to devices) over the internet (my PC has Internet) using my laptop. Anydesk TCP Tunneling or Public IP.

I want to connect my SSH server device (192.168.1.55) from my laptop.

[image]

I try this command.
ssh -L 2222:192.168.1.55:22 admin@192.168.1.50

Comment: `telnet` should never be used as there is no secure implementation of it - SSH should always be used. Unless the modem has a static WAN IP from the ISP, a DDNS would be required and configured on the router, then a DNAT firewall rule on the router would be created to forward WAN port <#> to LAN <IP address> and port <#> the SSH server is running on. **Do _NOT_ expose a Telnet server to WAN in any way**

Comment: Simply question, are you behind a CGNAT, if you are then what you want cannot be acheived.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a tempoary comment.